# How to get the directory of a plist file?

Tags: ios, plist

I have created an plist file within my project. Now i want to save date to it from within the application and also read from it. In order to do that i need to get its location and directory. Is that possible?

Comment: NSDictionary file? what's that? maybe plist file?

Comment: Yes i mean plist. I corrected it. thanks

Comment: In your project (build time) or in your app (run time)?

Comment: Within the application. While running the application and actually using it. (its supposed to contain the list of the users favorites)

Comment: What kind of object do you have to represent the file?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want not only read data from the file but also write to it you need to copy that file into Documents directory. It may be done like this:

```
NSFileManager *fileManger=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error; 
NSArray *pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString *doumentDirectoryPath=[pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *destinationPath= [doumentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDictionary.plist"];


if ([fileManger fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]){

return;
}
 NSString *sourcePath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDictionary.plist"];

 [fileManger copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];
```

You should call this code on application's launch. Now you can obtain the plist and turn it into a dictionary:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"myDictionary" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"]];
  NSMutableDictionary *plistDict;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filename]) {
    plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
}
```

If you wish to write to it now you need to do the following:

```
[plistDict setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"];

BOOL didWriteToFile = [plistDict writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
if (didWriteToFile) {
    NSLog(@"Did Write!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Didn't write!");
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the first part. The second and third makes sense (even though i get the Didnt Write message!)

Comment: the first part is needed cause you wanna change the contents of the file. Your initial plist file is located in the applcation's bundle which is read-only, so you need to copy it into Documents directory. Otherwise you won't write to it

Comment: You can't write but can you get the file? Do you successfully obtain it?

Comment: Yeah i guess its becuase i didnt include the first part.

Comment: Its strange but when i put the first and second part in the beggining of the viewdidload it fails to launch the view. i just get a white screen!